# Controlling Display of Methods In Template

Tags: django, formatting, templates, methods

I have the following in a view (foreign key relationships via _set):

```
srvr = Server.objects.get(name=q)
return render_to_response('search_results.html',
    {'drv': srvr.drive_set.all(), 'memry': srvr.memory_set.all(), 'query': q})
```

The results template includes:

```
{% if drv %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ drv }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endif %}
{% if memry %}
     <li>{{ memry }}</li>
 {% endif %}
```

The output looks like this:

```
[<Drive: IBM IBM-500 1111111 500Gb SATA>, <Drive: IBM IBM-500 2222222 500Gb SATA]  
[<Memory: Samsung 512>, <Memory: Samsung 512>, <Memory: Samsung 512>]
```

I know this the result of the "**unicode()**" method in the "Drive" and "Memory" classes.

How can I control the output/formatting so that the brackets and class name don't appear, and only specific fields. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drv` and `memry` are going to be iterable, and you can move through them with the `for` tag...

```
{% if drv %}
<table>
    {% for d in drv %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ d.name }}</td><td>{{ d.size }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
```

The `.name` and `.size` are properties of whatever Model `d` represents.  Fill this in with whatever details actually exist that you're looking to render.

Comment: Awesome. d seems to be an arbitrary specification. Am I correct ?

Comment: Uhm, `enumerables` => `iterable`, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @michael -- yes, that's just a variable name that you can pick.

Comment: @peter -- ah that's right python calls them iterable (other languages call the same data type enumerable)